# How to calculate 1cm equal ? px in website?

Tags: javascript

How to calculate 1cm equal ? px in website?

For screen dpr = 1, 1 cm = ppi / 2.54 / dpr. The actual cm is equal to the cm in the screen. But dpr != 1, the actual cm is not equal to the screen cm.

This [website](https://www.piliapp.com/actual-size/cm-ruler/) effect is what I want: screen length is physical length. But I do not know how to do that.

> Addition: If just use in laptop screen or desktop screen. Any way to achieve that? (normal desktop, dpr is usually 1. The main point is for laptop, some are Retina screen)

Comment: You can use the PPI of the screen with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Comment: In short, you can't reliably calculate actual units. Consider that the user might be using a projector or connecting to a TV of unknown dimensions. The browser has extremely limited knowledge of such cases.

Comment: If just use in laptop screen or desktop screen. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: The website you linked to is not accurate at all. I measured the 30cm ruler at 27.3cm in the real world

Comment: After entering the screen size it is still not accurate. I got 29.1cm for the 30cm ruler on screen.

Comment: You should select your screen size before you accurate. I do that and accurate correctly [mac air m1 13.3inch(2560 × 1600)].

Answer (score -1):

> How to calculate 1cm equal ? px in website?

In CSS, `cm` is a valid length unit.

So, in order to translate `cm` values into `px` values, we can style a series of elements - for instance, `<hr>` (*thematic break*) using `cm` and then use:

- `window.getComputedStyle(myElement).width`

to find out the `width` in pixels.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const thematicBreaks = document.querySelectorAll('hr');

thematicBreaks.forEach((hr, i) => {
  hrWidth = window.getComputedStyle(hr).width;
  console.info((i + 1) + 'cm is ' + hrWidth);
});
```

```css
hr {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

hr:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 1cm;
}

hr:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 2cm;
}

hr:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 3cm;
}

hr:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 4cm;
}

hr:nth-of-type(5) {
  width: 5cm;
}

hr:nth-of-type(6) {
  width: 6cm;
}
```

```html
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: Thanks for answer. But measured with a physical ruler, the lengths are not equal when ppi is 227 and dpr is 2.